# Getting Error When Using SET PROCEDURE TO

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

First let me say that I am very, very new to FoxPro and finding just the basics a bit of a learning curve.

I am attempting to create a program file (.prg) that has some public functions that I can call from my main code. I have added the program file "**publicfunctions.prg**" and included a simple function that returns a hard coded literal (just trying to make the mechanics work)

```
*!* This function is in the publicfunctions.prg file
FUNCTION GetFieldValue
    RETURN 'This is the value'
ENDFUNC
```

Then in my main program I attempt to use it but I am getting the error that the file does not exist. Here is the entirety of the code in the main program

```
*!* This is the main program logic    
SET PROCEDURE TO publicfunctions.prg

PRIVATE sFieldValue = ''

sFieldValue = GetFieldValue()
```

The error that I am getting is on the '**SET PROCEDURE TO publicfunctions.prg**' statement. It is: "**File 'publicfunctions.prg" does not exist.**"

I'm guessing that it can't find it because the default directory is not set to the path where the file exists. I tried adding the "**SET DEFAULT TO**" statement prior to the "**SET PROCEDURE TO**" statement but it didn't change the outcome at all.

I don't want to hard code the path so I guess my questions are these:

1. Is my assumption correct about the default directory?
2. If #1 is true then how can I set the default directory to the directory where the main program file is?
3. Am I calling the function correctly? (If it can find it of course)

**UPDATE**
Per Hank's questions below I have added this additional information:
The file "**publicfunctions.prg**" was added to the project using the "**New**" button on the Project Manager and the physical file is sitting right next to the "**Main.prg**" file in the file system folder.

[image]

[image]

**I am using Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9.0**

Any and all help will be truly appreciated.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VFP maintains a search path (which is separate from the Windows/DOS search path), which it will search for any PRGs, DBFs, etc that you reference in your code.

You can check its current setting with the SET('PATH') function, and set it with SET PATH TO.  These places are searched in addition to whatever the current default directory (which you can verify with the SET('DEFAULT') and CURDIR() functions.

This will show what these currently are:

```
WAIT WINDOW 'Path: ' + SET('PATH') + CHR(13)+CHR(10) + 'Default drive: ' + SET('Default') + CHR(13)+CHR(10) + 'Current directory: ' + CURDIR()
```

These are documented well in VFP's help - check there for a much better explanation.

Comment: LAK . . . thanks you for the excellent information. I'll be using that a lot I'm sure. Is there a way to determine the directory where the currently executing program file resides? If I could get that then I could use the SET PATH TO statement to change it. I ran the code you provided and the directories listed were nowhere near the actual PJX or PRG files that were executing.

Comment: I realize this may not be necessary for compiling the program as I can add the path to the Search Paths setting in the options, but it could be very helpful when attempting to open tables and other files.

Comment: I just figured out why I was getting the values I was. The CURDIR() function was returning the values relative to the currently running executable file. When running the code from within the FoxPro IDE that file is the FoxPro.exe not the program file that is currently running in the debugger. When i compiled the app to an exe it returned the appropriate information. Thanks to LAK for all of the very useful information.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.  I don't actually use VFP's 'Projects' (our application here has been developed since 1988 or so and we never fitted it into VFP's more modern ways of doing things), so I didn't offer specific advice about how they relate to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

One other comment here. Since you're new at VFP, you might as well start off on the right foot. Most VFP experts recommend not using procedure files. Put each function or procedure in a separate PRG file with the routine name as the file name. For example, your GetFieldValue function should be in GetFieldValue.PRG.

SET PROCEDURE goes back to early Xbase days before there was a Project Manager.

Comment: Tamar . . . Thanks for the information. I always like to know the generally accepted rules to good form in the environment I'm using. I am actually just trying to learn enough to keep several (very poorly written) FoxPro applications afloat until they can be replaced. So I won't actually be doing any "real" development. But again, thanks. I like knowing as much as I can.

Answer (score 2):

As Tamar has mentioned about trying to avoid using such "SET PROCEDURE" file, I would STRONGLY recommend having a well structured directory for your project.  Having all the files all in one place can be a total pain... Historically, I've done something like

```
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\classes
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\data
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\forms
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\graphics
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\prgs
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\reports
```

Then, respectively put your files in their respective locations.  Your add them to your project manager the same way and keep the "relative" path to the files.

As noted above, having your "Data" for the application separate makes for easy copy/paste of backup, simulate, debug testing of data sets over and over when needed.  When trying to open your files, you can reference opening files based on a qualified path + table name INSTEAD of using "SET PATH".   Too many times in the past have I had systems that relied on "SET PATH", and would choke, or find a file that was an old version to something and NOT be the one expected.  My approach is... If I can't find it WHY.  Find it, put it in the proper location and then continue.

As mentioned with the data, say you have tables "customers" and "orders" in the "data" directory.  You could have a variable and refer to that in both querying, or opening files...

```
PUBLIC myDataPath as String
myDataPath = "Data\"

use ( myDataPath + "Customers" )
select 0
use ( myDataPath + "Orders" )
```

If trying to query, you could do something like

```
select ;
      c.FirstName, ;
      c.LastName, ;
      o.OrderID, ;
      o.OrderDate ;
   from ;
      ( myDataPath + "Customers" ) c ;
         JOIN ( myDataPath + "Orders" ) o ;
            on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID ;
   into ;
      cursor C_SomeSampleResult READWRITE
```

This way you'll NEVER have an ambiguous WHICH table version does it THINK its trying to get data from.  Again, if it can't find the file, you have a bigger problem to resolve first.

Comment: DRapp, excellent addition to this thread. A lot of very useful information. I think I have learned more in the last day as a result of all the comments and answers in this thread than in the previous three weeks of pouring over (did I mention the very poorly written) code in the tens of thousands of lines that constitute these programs that I'm, all of a sudden, supporting.Thanks again to all who provided insight.

Comment: @dscarr, I'll even give a one-up for you... Being new to the realm of VFP world, and it's learning curve, if you want, I would offer you my personal email to help mentoring / guiding on what will obviously become a laundry list of findings...  Let me know, and I'll post my email and remove it once you've taken it down.

Comment: I would appreciate that greatly. I promise to perform the appropriate amount of due diligence before contacting you. I seem to have found myself in a situation supporting somewhere in the neighborhood of 20 end user written VFP programs having never looked at a single line of the code before. I'll take all of the help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your application to run anywhere you want to put in the programs and table.

You just have to add this...

```
SET DEFAULT TO SYS(5)+CURDIR()
SET PATH TO SYS(5)+CURDIR()
```

**PS**. Take note that this would only take effect when the project is in distributive (.exe) code only.  You have to set the path and default at the development stage of the program.

Answer (score 1):

With FoxPro, the file 'has' to be in the search path.  So if your building a project, add the file publicfunctions.prg to the project file under the code tab, if you're not building a project make sure that in the Options you have the folder where the prg located can be seen.

Also it helps if we know what version of Fox you're using.

Comment: Hank . . . thanks for the reply. As I noted in the update to the post the program was added through the Task Manager and is sitting right next to Main.prg. I am using VFP 9.0

Comment: You can find the current working directory by using sys(2003) 
in your code put something like
lcWhereAmI=SYS(2003)
If you want to see where a particular file is use
    lcWhereAreDataFiles=FULLPATH('sysadmin.dbc',1)

That will give you the complete path to that particular file

To set your search parameters in development 
In VFP 9 go to  tools-> options -> file locations click on the 'File Locations' tab, go to 'search path' and make sure the folder that contains your prg file is listed there.  Click on make default and then everytime you're in development mode Fox will find it for you

Comment: Hank . . . Thanks again for more valuable information. I found the Search Path setting in the Options and that allowed my program to find all the files it needed.