# VFP 9 sp2 project PRGs not found even though they are there

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have a VFP 9 project (.PJX) with a few PRG files included. Some PRG files are not in the same folder as the PJX file.  When I try to RUN my project, either from FoxPro or even after I build the EXE, it tells me that the PRGs which are not in the same folder are NOT FOUND.  But they are there for sure.  When and if I move those PRGs to the same folder as the PJX file, then all is good.  I started running into this ON and OFF for a while now, and I have no idea what causes this.  Any ideas how I can get rid of this problem?

You were giving a similar example of a project and directories with diff PRGs, SCXs, etc  here  [Getting Error When Using SET PROCEDURE TO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415447/getting-error-when-using-set-procedure-to)
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\prgs
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\forms
C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\graphics

Answer (score 2):

SET PATH to the relevant folders before running your code. That should solve IDE issues. For the EXE, as long as the programs are included in the PJX, they should be built into the EXE. So there must be something else going on. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

In your main program:

```
set procedure to myprog1 additive
set procedure to progs\myprog2 additive
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You're using SET PROCEDURE, but you're pointing to folders. That's not right. SET PROCEDURE points to PRG files that contain multiple routine. Use SET PATH to point to folders.